# How do I define a variable in a namespace with "using namespace"?

Tags: c++

So I have a namespace `thing` with `extern int` variables declared in a header. I'm trying to define them in a .cpp with `using namespace thing;` to simplify initialization, but it doesn't seem to work the way I expected when trying to define a variable in `thing.cpp`. What gives?

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "thing.hpp"

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n%d\n",thing::a,thing::func());
    printf("Zero initialized array:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d",thing::array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

thing.hpp:

```
#pragma once

namespace thing {
    extern int
        a,
        b,
        array[10];
    extern int func();
}
```

thing.cpp

```
#include "thing.hpp"

using namespace thing;

// I wanted to do the same thing with 'a' for all variables
int a,thing::b,thing::array[10];

int thing::func() {
    return 12345;
}
```

error:

```
/tmp/ccLbeQXP.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `thing::a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you compile and link thing.cpp to your final program?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, the code works fine when I use ```thing::a``` instead of just ```a```

Comment: Sure, you must fully qualify your symbol names, unless you do `using thing::a;`  statements for all the symbols defined in the .cpp file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So what rule makes it so I can't use ```using namespace thing```? If I include ```iostream``` in the header, and ```using namespace std``` in the .cpp I can use it's functions/methods without the ```std``` namespace prefix just fine

Comment: Why not wrap the contents of `thing.cpp` in `namespace thing { ... }` like you did with `thing.hpp`?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks - that works, but I'm still not sure what is going wrong in my program.

Comment: @ankien I answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using namespace thing` allows you to use identifiers from the `thing` namespace without prefixing them with `thing::`. It effectively pulls them into the namespace where the `using` directive is (or the global namespace).

It doesn't put further definitions *into* the namespace `thing`. So when you define `int a;`, it's just in the global namespace. You need to use `int thing::a;` or `namespace thing { int a; }` to define it in the namespace.

Comment: Great, I've changed the question title to match the answer I was looking for.